# How can I quickly search the content of my clipboard in vimperator?

Tags: vimperator

I've added several sites that allow me to geolocate IP addresses as Firefox search engines.

These can be searched in Vimperator like this:

> o ipsearch IP_address
>
> o ipsearch2 IP_address

What I want to do now is set up a quickmark or some kind of shortcut that allows me to press one key (i) and then automatically search *ipsearch* and *ipsearch2* for whatever is saved in my clipboard.  Is there a way to set something like this up in Vimperator?

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://superuser.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: This does seem to be a reasonable question about a specific problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not? What can be represented as sequence of keystrokes, can be mapped – that’s a general idea of Vim-like interfaces.

```
nmap <Leader>ip oipsearch<Space><S-Ins>
```

This works in [Pentadactyl](http://5digits.org/), and though I did not test it in Vimperator, I guess, there should not be any difference.

Comment: Based on your code, this is the line I ended up using: `nnoremap i oipsearch<Space><S-Ins>, ipsearch2<Space><S-Ins>, ipsearch3<Space><S-Ins>`